# Is it possible to deploy multiple war files under the same deployment path?

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Let's say I have:

- `foo.war`
- `bar.war`

Is it possible that I deploy them both somehow to the same deployment path? E.g., to access it at:

- http://localhost/baz

Are the content of the war files merged somehow? How are file conflicts handled (e.g., let's say both of them has an `index.jsp` file)?

Thx in advnace!

Comment: May we ask why you are thinking of doing this?

Comment: Complicated :D Splitting a huge legacy app. This could save me a lot of regression testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servlet specification explicitly forbids this.  Deployed web applications may not have identical or overlapping context roots.  From the Servlet 3.0 specification, section 10.5:

> Since the context path of an application determines the URL namespace of the contents of the Web application, Web containers must reject Web applications defining a context path that could cause potential conflicts in this URL namespace. This may occur, for example, by attempting to deploy a second Web application with the same context path.

Answer (score 2):

Yes & no.

I don't think it's possible to somehow merge them into the same file system path within a servlet container like Tomcat (unless you were to write some kind of complicated, intelligent script to do so).  For starters, each .war will have a `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, and each will rely on the contents of its own file to function -- which would win?

But you conceivably could...

- Deploy to 2 different contexts (or containers, or hosts), and employ some kind of load balancer (hardware or software) to route some requests to one, other requests to the other.
- Use an "overlay" strategy (such as [Maven Overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)) to make a second (and final) .war that is a derivative and extension of another .war file

Comment: So which WAR of the two WARs would Tomcat then choose to deploy?

Comment: Thanks Drew, I got the same impression. Overlays could work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: WRT the Overlay approach -- it's not Tomcat, but you who has to deploy the .war file.  You have to choose (and deploy) the derivative file.

Comment: Clarification on the first point - if each war supports an identifiable set of URL paths then the web server sitting in front of Tomcat could route to the appropriate web app.  For example, /foo/a/b/c could be routed to /foo-app/foo/a/b/c while /bar/a/b/c could be routed to /bar-app/bar/a/b/c.